# How to run this macro to each row?

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I'm a complete noob on doing VBA and i'm trying to find some way to run a more smarter code to repeat this process below for around 250 subsequent rows. The only cells which will vary across the rows are those who are with **. Can somebody lend me a hand?

*The practical side of this actions stands for copy a value from a sheet A, paste on sheet B, copy the generated value on B and then transfer to A.*

```
Worksheets("CUSTO POR PRODUTO").Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("METODO ABSORÇAO TODOS PUXADORES").Range("**A4**").Value
Worksheets("METODO ABSORÇAO TODOS PUXADORES").Range("**E4**").Value = Worksheets("CUSTO POR PRODUTO").Range("D12").Value

Worksheets("CUSTO POR PRODUTO").Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("METODO ABSORÇAO TODOS PUXADORES").Range("**A5**").Value
Worksheets("METODO ABSORÇAO TODOS PUXADORES").Range("**E5**").Value = Worksheets("CUSTO POR PRODUTO").Range("D12").Value

Worksheets("CUSTO POR PRODUTO").Range("B3").Value = Worksheets("METODO ABSORÇAO TODOS PUXADORES").Range("**A6**").Value
Worksheets("METODO ABSORÇAO TODOS PUXADORES").Range("**E6**").Value = Worksheets("CUSTO POR PRODUTO").Range("D12").Value
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

### Copy Values by Assignment

- This is the `For Next` approach. You can also use the `For Each Next` approach and additionally combine it with using arrays to increase performance.
- At this stage variables 'don't cost a thing'. So use them.
- Choose one of the three ways.

**The Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub CopyValuesRange()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 4
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("CUSTO POR PRODUTO")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("METODO ABSORÇAO TODOS PUXADORES")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws2.Range("A" & ws2.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        ws1.Range("B3").Value = ws2.Range("A" & i).Value
        ws2.Range("E" & i).Value = ws1.Range("D12").Value
    Next i

End Sub

Sub CopyValuesCellsStrings()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 4
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("CUSTO POR PRODUTO")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("METODO ABSORÇAO TODOS PUXADORES")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        ws1.Cells(3, "B").Value = ws2.Cells(i, "A").Value
        ws2.Cells(i, "E").Value = ws1.Cells(12, "D").Value
    Next i

End Sub

Sub CopyValuesCellsNumbers()
    
    Const FirstRow As Long = 4
    
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' The workbook containing this code.
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet
    Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("CUSTO POR PRODUTO")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("METODO ABSORÇAO TODOS PUXADORES")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = ws2.Cells(ws2.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    Dim i As Long
    
    For i = FirstRow To LastRow
        ws1.Cells(3, 2).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value
        ws2.Cells(i, 5).Value = ws1.Cells(12, 4).Value
    Next i

End Sub
```